# How to read a file within .jar which is dependency of .war file

Tags: java, maven

I would like to know how to read a file within .jar which is dependency of .war file.

I have the following struct:

```
JAR1.jar 
   - src/main/java
        Test.java
        Charger.java
   - src/main/resources
        Propiedad.txt
```

Charger.java use the file `Propiedad.txt`, with the follows code:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
URL u = classLoader.getResource("Propiedad.txt");
File file = new File(u.getFile());
```

When I have created the .jar file and I have running the application with the IDE, calling to class `Test.class` (which has the main method and It calls Charger class) does not have problem with found the `Propiedad.txt`, however my problem begins when I use the JAR1.java like dependency in a web application (within pom.xml with maven), in a WAR1, with the follows struct:

```
WAR1.war 
   - JavaSource
        Servlet.java
   - MavenDependencies
        JAR1.jar
```

When Servlet.java (It belongs to WAR1.war) calls Charger class from JAR1.jar, then the method `classLoader.getResource(nombre);` (it belong to JAR1.jar) return null value.

Someone knows, how can I do to the JAR1.jar always found the Propiedad.txt file (even when it is used like dependency in a .war file).

Regards.

Comment: The first part of your code look ok...only the part `File file = ...` is the wrong path. You need to use `getClass().getResourcesAsStream("/...");` and use an input stream to read that file?...

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. The reason to use getResource is beacause I am going to use the method SchemaFactory.newInstance (File schema) (I will validate a xml with a schema). I wrote this code  with txt.file to try to simplify the code for not confuse the reader, but really I need to get the file path to create an object File, also I tried to use "/..."  with getResoruce, but no worked.

Comment: You can't read a file via File ()..within a JAR file cause there does not exist a thing like a file system underneath..So a validation of an XML should be possible using InputStream etc...apart from that the question is why do you need to validate the XML against a schema which should be done before packing that file into the resulting jar file (difference runtime / buildtime)...

Comment: Yes, It is working with etClass().getResourcesAsStream("/...");. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: If you use Spring, you could make with ClassPathResource. Here the reference: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-classpath-file-access